# VBA in Excel is skipping 2nd Do Until Loop Entirely

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have been working on some code which contains several Do Until Loops but when I run it the first loop works as expected but the second and other loops are completely bypassed.

I have run the individual loops in independent sub routines and they worked as needed.

I have also checked previous threads and can't seem to find an example of the same problem.

I initially tried re-declaring `i = 2` for the second loop thinking `i` still valued > than `lastRow` from the first loop.
On top of this I have also tried changing the variable from `i` to `j` for the second loop but this also made no difference.

Here an example of the code I am using:

```
Dim i As Long
i = 2   
Do Until i > lastRow
     Cells(i, 16).Select
     If ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-13) <> "Invoice" Then
        ActiveCell = ""
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12) <> "" Then
        ActiveCell = ""
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-9) <> "Usage Actual" Then
        ActiveCell = ""
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3) = "Final" Then
        ActiveCell = ""
        Else: ActiveCell. _
        FormulaR1C1 = ' vlookup formula to data source
        End If
     i = i + 1
Loop

        ' Additional code to paste out formula and save work book   
Dim j As Long   
j = 2   
Do Until j > lastRow
' from here the process skips right past the next loop to the Additional code to paste out formula and save work book noted below
     Cells(j, 17).Select
     If ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-1) = "Yes" Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ' vlookup formula to data source
        Else: ActiveCell = ""
        End If
     j = j + 1
Loop
        ' Additional code to paste out formula and save work book
```

I have been working on this for several days and have run out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried debugging by putting a breakpoint on `Do Until j > lastRow`? It would be interesting to see what happens when that line of code is executed...

Comment: I have added a `MsgBox` in both loops, it is going inside both the loops.

Comment: I can't replicate this either. I'm guessing that either the column offset is wrong in the second loop or it isn't finding any cells with "Yes" in them. If it relies on the formula results in the first loop, try putting `ActiveSheet.Calculate` between them.

Comment: I have run through all of the loops using the debugger and it runs up to selecting the line Cells(j, 17).Select and then jumps to ' Additional code to paste out formula and save work book. I also added ActiveSheet.Calculate with no change to the problem (never used that before so thank you for giving me an excuse to use it). And as for the offset references, I ran the loops as independent subs and they all performed as desired - now wearing my baffled face again.

Comment: Hi Raju - when you added in the MagBox's where did you place them in the loop? was it before or after line Cells(j, 17).Select ?

Comment: What is the value of `lastRow` when that happens? Is it in a global variable that is being reset in the process of "Additional code to paste out formula and save work book"?

Comment: Hi Comintern. lastRow value is around 96k and is defined by a used range count of a column with confirmed data in each cell. It will differ each time the code is run as the reports that feed it range in size from 90k to 150k lines. This is the reason I had to Dim i as long as it was originally an interger but that only allowed a count up to 32676 lines - not nearly big enough.

Comment: Is that  what it *should* be, or what it *is* when you set a break-point?

Comment: `lastrow`is definitely the problem, and maybe `option explicit`. what is the value of lastrow ? As i read it, lastrow=0

Answer (score 1):

I have finally managed to get the code to work.
The method I ended up using involved 2 changes.

Firstly I gave each loop it's own Do Until variable - where the code posted above started with i as the first variable, the next became j, then k and so on.

This on it's own did not initially resolve the issue until I added additional processes between each loop.

For example, following the first loop I added code to perform a lookup in another column and to copy that lookup down to lastRow but without using a loop to do it. I followed this with the next loop and followed that with further additional code, also not requiring a loop to complete.

Fortunately I had enough additional processes to break up all of the loops in the project. Although I still believe running multiple loops one after another shouldn't be a problem, I have yet to find a more effective solution.